# AnythingSlider thumbnails not sliding

Tags: jquery, carousel, thumbnails, anythingslider

I've been struggling with this and couldn't find the solution in the documentation. AnythingSlider is creating the thumbnails as desired but they just won't move. They seem to be fixed and it's only displaying 9 thumbnails. The problem is when I add more than 9 photos the thumbnails stack in the next line instead of being added in the current and hiding.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('#slider1')
              .anythingSlider({
               navigationFormatter : function(i, panel){ // add thumbnails as navigation links
                return '<img src="images/thumbs' + ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',][i - 1] + '.jpg">';
               },
                // Callback when the plugin finished initializing
                onInitialized: function(e, slider) {

                    var time = 1000, // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
                        range = 50,  // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the slider
                        x = 0, t = 0, touch = "ontouchend" in document,
                        st = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
                        mv = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
                        en = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

                    slider.$window.add( slider.$controls )
                        .bind(st, function(e){
                            // prevent image drag (Firefox)
                            e.preventDefault();
                            t = (new Date()).getTime();
                            x = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX; 
                        })
                        .bind(en, function(e){
                            t = 0; x = 0;
                        })
                        .bind(mv, function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var newx = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
                            r = (x === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(newx - x),
                            // allow if movement < 1 sec
                            ct = (new Date()).getTime();
                            if (t !== 0 && ct - t < time && r > range) {
                                if (newx < x) { 
                                    if ($(this).hasClass('anythingControls')) {
                                        slider.$controls.find('.next').trigger('click');
                                    } else {
                                        slider.goForward();
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                }
                                if (newx > x) {
                                    if ($(this).hasClass('anythingControls')) {
                                        slider.$controls.find('.prev').trigger('click');
                                    } else {
                                        slider.goBack(); 
                                    }
                                }
                                t = 0; x = 0;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                }
               });});});
```

Any idea of what could be wrong in this configuration?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running this in a `document.ready()` function or including the code after the `#slider1` element?

Comment: This code is in a .js file and it's loaded via header.js then executed when document it's ready.

Comment: Just making sure. The first thing that I thought of was making sure this was run after the DOM has loaded. I see a couple extra `});`'s at the end, but I am assuming those are extra that got copied into the question on accident. Try using Firebug or the error console and see if Javascript if throwing any errors on your code. You might try using Firebug to set some breakpoints inside the onInitialized function to verify that it is running.

Comment: I tried and I see no error, I think it's not configured properly because it's not eveng displaying the arrows. I'll keep researching and see if I can find the solution.

Comment: Try removing all the extra code you have, and just set up the default slider with `$('#slider1').anythingSlider();` to see if that loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the [`navigationSize` option](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#wiki-navigationsize) setting. By default it is `false` and doesn't limit the number of visible controls.

I believe [this is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/51/) you are trying to emulate.

Comment: Yes! That one, but with the difference of that instead of numbers I'm using images as thumbnails. I'll try it, it should be possible too. Thanks!